# Nested for loop not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

So when I have a nested for loop like such

```
<?php for ($i= 0; $i< 5; $i++)
{
    for ($x= 0; $x< 5; $x++)
    {
        echo $x;
    }

    echo "<br/>";
} ?>
```

it returns:

```
01234
01234
01234
01234
01234
```

So then why does the nested for loop below not work? Instead of starting each `$x` again, it just combines them together. So (assuming the results are the same as the above example) the first row will be `01234`, but the second row will be `0123456789`, with the `01234` being the same as the first row., and so on. So the 8th row will contain all the values from row 1 to 8.

```
<?php
try {
    $sql = "SELECT timetable.id as id, timetable.day as serviceday, timetable.station, timetable.departs as time, CURTIME(), 
CASE WHEN ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timetable.departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) > 120 THEN FLOOR(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timetable.departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0)/60) ELSE ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timetable.departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) END as departs, 
CASE WHEN ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timetable.departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) <= 120 THEN 'min' ELSE 'hrs' END as units, DATE_FORMAT(timetable.departs, '%l:%i %p') as time2, 
CASE WHEN timetable.platform != platformchange.platform THEN platformchange.platform ELSE timetable.platform END as platform,
 timetable.route, timetable.run, route.code, line.name, line.translink, station.name as terminus, line.colour, ns, a.departs as terminustime, IFNULL(c.id,-1) as cancel FROM timetable INNER JOIN route ON timetable.route = route.id INNER JOIN line ON route.line = line.id INNER JOIN station ON route.terminus = station.id INNER JOIN (SELECT departs, station, route, run FROM timetable) a ON a.station = station.id AND timetable.route = a.route AND timetable.run = a.run LEFT JOIN (SELECT service, platform FROM platformchange  WHERE day LIKE '%" . $day . "%') as platformchange ON timetable.id = platformchange.service LEFT JOIN overnight ON timetable.route = overnight.route AND timetable.run = overnight.run LEFT JOIN (SELECT cancel.id, cancel.route, cancel.run FROM cancel WHERE cancelday = CURDATE()) as c ON c.route = timetable.route AND c.run = timetable.run  WHERE timetable.station = " . $_GET['id'] . " AND timetable.departs > CURTIME() AND (timetable.day LIKE '%" . $day . "%' OR timetable.date = CURDATE()) AND IFNULL(c.id,-1) < 1 GROUP BY timetable.id ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 12";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e){

}

foreach($s as $row){
    $services[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'time' => $row['time'], 'platform' => $row['platform'], 'terminus' => $row['terminus'], 'colour' => $row['colour'], 'departs' => $row['departs'] . ' ' . $row['units'], 'route' => $row['route'], 'run' => $row['run'], 'time2' => $row['time2'], 'ns' => $row['ns'], 'terminustime' => $row['terminustime'], 'tl' => $row['translink']);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($services); $i++){
    try {
        $query = "SELECT station.name as station, station.distancefromcentral, ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) as orderby, CASE WHEN ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) > 120 THEN FLOOR(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0)/60) ELSE ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) END as departs, CASE WHEN ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(departs)/60 - TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())/60,0) > 120 THEN 'hrs' ELSE 'min' END as units, timetable.route, timetable.run, day, date, station.distancefromcentral
FROM timetable 
INNER JOIN station ON timetable.station = station.id 
LEFT JOIN overnight ON overnight.route = timetable.route AND overnight.run = timetable.run
WHERE (departs > '" . $services[$i]['time'] . "' AND (day LIKE '%" . $day . "%' OR date LIKE CURDATE()) AND timetable.route = " . $services[$i]['route'] . " 
AND timetable.run = " . $services[$i]['run'] . ")
OR ( overnight.id > 0 AND(day LIKE '%" . $nextday . "%' OR date LIKE DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) AND timetable.route = " . $services[$i]['route'] . " 
AND timetable.run = " . $services[$i]['run'] . ")  
ORDER BY date, 
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%w') = 0
      THEN `day` 
    END DESC,
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%w') <> 0
      THEN `day` 
    END ASC, 
  orderby ASC";
        $z = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $z->execute();
    }

    catch (PDOException $error){
        echo 'error';
    }

    foreach($z as $z){
        $stops[] = array('station' => $z['station'], 'departs' => $z['departs'] . ' ' . $z['units'], 'dist' => $z['distancefromcentral'], 'route' => $z['route'], 'run' => $z['run'], 'day' => $z['day'], 'orderby' => $z['orderby'], 'units' => $z['units']);
    }

    if(isset($stops)){                          
        for($x = 0; $x < count($stops); $x++){
            echo $x;
        }
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

So here is an example of just 2 rows

```
012345678910111213
012345678910111213141516
```

However the second row only has 3 values, so should only be `012`. It's not separating them per `$i`, just combining them

If I'm not explaining it well I apologise

Comment: What exactly do you expect from first example?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev which example?

Comment: In your 1st example the `$x` is reset on each iteration of `$i` as it calls `for ($x= 0;`

Comment: @IvanNevostruev the simple one at the top? What I have below it

Comment: "So then why does this nested for loop not work?" My question it what exactly you think is wrong here?

Comment: In your 2nd code. You are just executing the query `$s->execute();`/`$z->execute();` and trying to access those `foreach($s`/`foreach($z` which do not have the returned data. You need to fetch them `$s_all = $s->fetchAll()`/`$z_all = $z->fetchAll()` and loop through those fetched rows -> `foreach($s_all`/`foreach($z_all`

Comment: @IvanNevostruev sigh, you don't get it. The opening example works, the code with the SQL doesn't

Comment: I see. So that's what you expect as result to your last piece of code.

Comment: @Sean that doesn't seem to be working, could you explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is this part

```
foreach($z as $z){
    $stops[] = array('station' => $z['station'], 'departs' => $z['departs'] . ' ' . $z['units'], 'dist' => $z['distancefromcentral'], 'route' => $z['route'], 'run' => $z['run'], 'day' => $z['day'], 'orderby' => $z['orderby'], 'units' => $z['units']);
}
```

On each loop you are adding to `$stops`, so if the 1st had 14, then the 2nd would add 3 more, so it would be 17 not just 3.

You can either reset the array before

```
$stops = array();
foreach($z as $z){
 ...
```

Or add the `$i` as a key

```
foreach($z as $z){
    $stops[$i][] = array('station' => $z['station'], 'departs' => $z['departs'] . ' ' . $z['units'], 'dist' => $z['distancefromcentral'], 'route' => $z['route'], 'run' => $z['run'], 'day' => $z['day'], 'orderby' => $z['orderby'], 'units' => $z['units']);
}
if(isset($stops[$i])){                          
    for($x = 0; $x < count($stops[$i]); $x++){
        echo $x;
    }
}
```